# Is there a better/easier way to solve this matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -1 & -1 & 0 &|&30 \\
-1 & 4 & 0 & -1&|&60 \\
-1 & 0 & 4 & -1&|&40 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 4&|&70
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

What's the best way to solve the matrix above? There's a clear pattern of the diagonal 4's and 0's and the -1's so I feel like there has to be a better way of doing things rather than using scaling and row reduction.

If I do those methods I end up with messy fractions.

**My Step 1:**

New Row 2 = (1/4)Row 1 + Row 2

Even at step 1 I can tell the whole thing will be messy with fractions.

Is there a better way to solve this matrix? Or am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add all four rows to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 &2 &2 &2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}= 200 $$

or

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 &1 &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}= 100 $$

Add that to every row to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}5 &0 &0 &1\\ 0 & 5 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 5 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}130\\160\\140\\170\end{pmatrix} $$

Now you have two separated 2x2 systems. Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks, that's super interesting. is there a name for that process?

Comment: I call it "sharply looking at the equation until you have an idea" :D No idea if there is a formal name for it. Also, can you please accept this answer? Then others will know that there is an viable answer here :)

Comment: sure thing, i forgot i could do that cause i got more reputation now. also im still thinking this would be messy yea? cause like: new row 4 = row 1(-1/5) so then it'll be (-1/5) + 5 which is 4/5ths which is still messy, or is that just no other way, or am i doing it wrong

Comment: you can do row1-5*row4, if you dislike fractions. But having one fraction and then multiplying the equation by 5/4 is not that bad.

Comment: aight thx dawg, i gotchu

Comment: yo bro came back to thank u again about how beast this solution was, even the prof was impressed cause this I was the only one to do it this way. thx again bro. credits all urs. genius solution

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I am really happy that an answer from here actually had a positive impact on someone in real life :)

Comment: Amen. It was super crazy. I'm surprised not even the smarter people in my class saw it like that. You the man. Respect.